# Google Analytics - how to set appName variable using gtag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I found this sample to set the appName variable in the tracking code:

ga('set', 'appName', 'MyApp');

How can I set appName using the Global Site Tag (gtag.js) syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out!

gtag('config', 'UA-111111111-1');

**gtag('event', 'screen_view', {'app_name': 'MyApp'});**